# how to execute several methods with a single click?

Tags: c#, button, browser

I want to automatically execute many buttons clicking only on the first, so I used in each button:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=
    new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(Button2_Click);
```

However the program crashes. How I can start the execution of several methods one by one (each method must wait until the previous ends)?

to simplify, my first method must load a web page, the second must fill in the fields existing in the page back. when I execute these two methods separately all goes well, but if I execute in a single button the two methods
Method1 ();
method2 ();
it gives me an error on line
HtmlElement = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById txtbox ("txtbox1");
it does not find the element, so could be the page has not yet been download, so I put each method in a button, and I added to the first button, the line
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted + = new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler (Button2_Click);
so when the webbrowser download page, the button will execute the second, but still the same error: can not find txtbox1.

Comment: Just saying "the program crashes" doesn't tell us much. What happens, *exactly*? Is an exception thrown? If so, what's the exception?

Comment: It would really help if you could give us more code so we can see what you are trying to achieve. One line of code and a vague explanation of the issue won't help us help you.

Answer (score 3):

the easy way put the methods calls into your listener's method Button2_Click like this

```
   {
method1();
    method2();
    method3();
    method4();
}
```

Comment: why don't call the second method at the end of the first? also try to use a boolean to check your textbox has been created. This is just an idea you might try it
`boolean txtboxcreated=false;
public void method1(){
..
new TextBox();
txtboxcreated=true;
..

if(txtboxcreated==true)
method2();
}`